# HttpError and IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I return `HttpError` (own, pretty formatted, error message for front-end) then I use handy `IHttpActionResult`?

```
public IHttpActionResult Delete(Guid id)
{
    HttpError error = null;

    // code omitted

    if (error != null) {
        // How can I achieve that?
        return BadRequest(error);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [ResponseMessageResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.responsemessageresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
public IHttpActionResult Error()
{
    var error = new HttpError();
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error));
}
```